# Mysql query to retrieve all rows in a table

Tags: mysql, jdbc, resultset

I want to retrieve and print all the rows of the table abc but this query is retrieving just single row.I cannot find the glitch.

```
String sql= "SELECT * FROM `abc`";
try {
    st = con.createStatement();
    rs= st.executeQuery(sql);
    rs.first();
    while(rs.next())
    { String x=rs.getString("x");
     String y=rs.getString("y");
     String z=rs.getString("z");
     String a=rs.getString("a");

     out.println(x);%><br><%
     out.println(y);%><br><%
     out.println(z);%><br><%
     out.println(a);%><br><hr>

     <%

    }
    rs.close();%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not Use `rs.first();`. Then Try this code:

```
String sql= "SELECT * FROM `abc`";
try {
    st = con.createStatement();
    rs= st.executeQuery(sql);
    while(rs.next())
    { 
     String x=rs.getString("x");
     String y=rs.getString("y");
     String z=rs.getString("z");
     String a=rs.getString("a");

     out.println(x);%><br><%
     out.println(y);%><br><%
     out.println(z);%><br><%
     out.println(a);%><br><hr>

     <%

    }
    rs.close();%>
```